# Edit list form with Visual Studio

Tags: list-form, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to figure out how I can edit the list forms in Visual Studio instead of SP designer, but seem unable to find anything about this, only how to create a new form. Please tell me it's possible to edit an existing form in VS instead of SP Designer.

I'm using SP 2010 and Visual Studio 2012

Comment: You should open the form in SPD and then copy the content. Create an application page in Visual Studio, paste the content and modify it as required.

Comment: Thanks. Which kind of application? which project type do I select in Visual Studio? is a simple empty aspx web application good enough?

Comment: Are you planning to package the form using Visual Studio? Or just want to edit the form and save it back via SPD?

Comment: I simply wanna edit the form and saving it.
saving it back via SPD would be acceptable if VS is not able to do so. Esentially I wanna do what SPD does, but in VS.

Comment: Ok in that case you can open VS and create a new web application project. Then add a web form or page to it. Then paste the form from SPD. In this approach you can only using VS as a text editor.

Comment: pasting the code from SPD into VS web form simply returns Master page error as I imagined it might. Esentially I was hoping I would be able to use VS in the same role as SPD, using split view

Comment: It also appears that when copying Aspx code into Visual Studio all id="" attributes/parameters are redefined to default values instead of retaining the value from the source, essentially making it useless for editing existing code.